# How can I copy multiple files via Bluetooth OBEX and 32feet?

Tags: android, vb.net, bluetooth, 32feet, obex

**What I want to achieve:**
Write a VB.NET program that grabs a folder structure on my Windows 8 and copies the structure to a base directory on my Samsung Galaxy S6 via Bluetooth.

I am using 32feet by *alanjmcf* - Thanks for providing this wonderful api.

**What I have managed so far:**
I wrote a VB.NET 32feet application that successfully copies 1 file from Windows to my Samsung Galaxy S6.

The code extract:

```
    Public Sub demo()
       Dim peer As Sockets.BluetoothDeviceInfo
       Dim req As ObexWebRequest

       For Each peer In New Sockets.BluetoothClient().DiscoverDevices()
           If peer.DeviceName = "Galaxy S6" Then
               req = New ObexWebRequest _
                    (peer.DeviceAddress, _
                     "obex://" + peer.DeviceAddress.ToString + "/" + "test.txt")
               req.ReadFile("c:\users\admin\documents\test.txt")
               req.GetResponse()
               Exit For
           End If
       Next
    End Sub
```

My Samsung mobile asks a confirmation. Upon my "Go" it receives the file.

**I would like to copy multiple files from a folder structure instead. And put them into an analogous folder structure in my Samsung mobile.**

I could of course iterate through my files and repeat the block above, possibly specifying folders in the URI,

**but my Samsung will ask my confirmation for each file, which is not manageable.**

What can I do?

Thanks and regards
S. Roy

Comment: You can `zip` the files, or make a `manifest file` (which contains what folder will the file will be extracted) + actual files compress it to zip then send it via `Bluetooth`. Make an `Android` app that listens for Bluetooth file transfer that also reads the manifest and extract the file to their designated folder.

Comment: Thanks conquistador. I will try that. I thought I could circumvent the Android app. But if that's what it takes...

Comment: I think you should install a Bluetooth FTP server application and then use OBEX FTP protocol instead of OBEX OPP.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by "confirmation" is that your Samsung mobile requests pairing by showing a PIN number? If so, then you need to stop the pairing request to be sent to clients from the VB.NET server.
I think you can do that by setting the *AuthenticationLevel* in your request.

For a **BluetoothClient** instance, I usually set the **Authenticate** property to false to stop request for pairing.

One more thing, when working with OBEX, I prefer to stop the OBEX Windows service from the services console, so it cannot interfere the Bluetooth communication.